# Создание формы вручную на Delphi

Tags: delphi

Хочу попробовать создать форму полностью вручную.

Пишу вручную модуль:

```
unit Unit2;
interface
uses Forms;
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  end;
implementation
end.
```

В обработчике нажатия кнопки пишу:

```
with TForm2.Create(Self) do
try
  ShowModal;
finally
  Free;
end;
```

При нажатии на кнопку выдает исключение:

```
Resource TForm2 not found
```

Возможно ли как-то (может быть хак какой) создавать формы полностью вручную, без задействования дельфийского механизма сохранения свойств форм в ресурсах?

Answer (score 4):

Касаемо ошибки: "Resource TForm2 not found". Можно подключить пустой файл dfm
к модулю формы и тогда форма будет нормально создаваться.

Dfm подключается через дерективу {$R}

Пример:

SecondForm.dfm

```
object SecondForm: TSecondForm
end
```

SecondForm.pas

```
unit SecondForm;

interface

uses
  Forms;

type

  TSecondForm = class(TForm)

  end;

procedure ShowSecondForm;

implementation

{$R SecondForm.dfm}

procedure ShowSecondForm;
var
  Form: TSecondForm;
begin
  Form := TSecondForm.Create(nil);
  try
    Form.ShowModal;
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

PS: такой трюк еще полезен при наследовании форм без dfm

**Дополнение**

Еще можно использовать конструктор [CreateNew](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CreateNew)

Answer (score 2):

Все получилось!
Нужно вместо стандартного конструктора **Create** использовать альтернативный конструктор **CreateNew**.

Answer (score 1):

При программном создании формы, нужно в конструктор передавать `nil` вместо `self`. А при создании динамических компонентов формы следует уже указывать родителем саму форму. Все должно быть логично: форма не может быть родителем для самой себя, но может и должна быть родителем для размещаемых на ней визуальных компонентов.

Вот здесь блестящая реализация задачи:
[Is it possible to dynamically create a form without having .dfm and .pas files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595380/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-create-form-without-having-dfm-and-pas-files) (см. ответ)

По сути, `.dfm` – это лишь подобие файла ресурсов, который хранит свойства формы. Во время компиляции/сборки эти свойства читаются и устанавливаются (читай: присваиваются).

У формы есть набор обязательных свойств, без которых она попросту не отобразится.